# How to count number of words for each row of a column and then convert to numeric?

Tags: r, regex

I have a column in a data frame that lists amenities found in a hotel location. I need to count how many amenities are in each row and then convert this to a number so I can then make another column with these numbers.

```
> airbnb$amenities[1:25]
 [1] "{TV,Internet,Wifi,\"Air conditioning\",\"Paid parking off premises\",Breakfast,Heating,\"Smoke detector\",\"Carbon monoxide detector\",\"First aid kit\",\"Safety card\",\"Fire extinguisher\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"Lock on bedroom door\",\"24-hour check-in\",Hangers,\"Hair dryer\",Iron,\"Laptop friendly workspace\",\"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_49\",\"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50\",\"Private entrance\",\"Hot water\",\"Patio or balcony\",\"Garden or backyard\",\"Luggage dropoff allowed\",\"Well-lit path to entrance\",\"Host greets you\"}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [2] "{TV,Wifi,\"Air conditioning\",Kitchen,\"Pets live on this property\",Cat(s),\"Free street parking\",Heating,Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke detector\",Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,\"Hair dryer\",Iron,\"Laptop friendly workspace\",\"Hot water\",\"Luggage dropoff allowed\",Other}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [3] "{TV,\"Cable TV\",Wifi,\"Air conditioning\",Pool,Kitchen,\"Free parking on premises\",Breakfast,Elevator,\"Hot tub\",\"Buzzer/wireless intercom\",Heating,\"Family/kid friendly\",Washer,\"Smoke detector\",\"First aid kit\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"24-hour check-in\",Hangers,\"Hair dryer\",Iron,\"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50\"}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 [4] "{Internet,Wifi,Pool,Kitchen,\"Free street parking\",\"Buzzer/wireless intercom\",Heating,\"Smoke detector\",Essentials,Hangers,Iron,\"Hot water\",Microwave,\"Coffee maker\",Refrigerator,\"Dishes and silverware\",\"Cooking basics\",\"BBQ grill\",\"Garden or backyard\",\"Long term stays allowed\",\"Host greets you\"}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [5] "{TV,Internet,Wifi,\"Air conditioning\",Kitchen,\"Paid parking off premises\",Elevator,\"Buzzer/wireless intercom\",Heating,Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke detector\",\"First aid kit\",\"Safety card\",Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,\"Hair dryer\",Iron,\"Laptop friendly workspace\",\"Hot water\",Microwave,Refrigerator,Dishwasher,\"Dishes and silverware\",\"Cooking basics\",Oven,Stove,\"Long term stays allowed\",Other}"
```

I'm familiar with using grep, gsub and the like but I'm confused as to how to count within each row. I thought that grep('[a-z]', airbnb$amenities) might work to somehow count the patterns in each row but am still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `str_count` to count the delimiter (`,`) and then add 1 to it to get the number of n-gram words

```
library(stringr)
airbnb$amenityCount <- str_count(airbnb$amenities, ",") + 1
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the word 'amenity' specifically. I mean actual amenities, like TV, Internet, WiFi, would be 3 amenities.

Comment: @LaurelDaly  Is there any identifier to look for those amenities

Comment: @LaurelDaly  I find some some words `en.hosting_amenity_50`.  Is there any pattern that you want to look for

Comment: If it is the total count of word groups, then `str_count(airbnb$amenities, ",") + 1`